# How do i reset the $get variable in my url

Tags: php

I have a page which is `www.example.com/viewbuyer.php?q=1&buyerid=1`

A form is entered onto the page and re-sets the same page with the following update:

```
$updateGoTo = "viewbuyer.php?q=2&buyerid=" . $row_buyer['buyerid'] . "";
```

However this url it actually goes to is `www.example.com/viewbuyer.php?q=2&buyerid=1&q=1&buyerid=1`

Obviously i dont want the variables in the URL already to pass over on the form submission.

I'm sure it's something simple but bit of a php noob.

Comment: put in  your form `method="post"` to use $_POST values

Comment: Would it be a simple case of making a POST instead of a GET?

Comment: can you include the code where you do redirect ?